# log4net logger configuration with ms access

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, log4net

my code seems to be working but it does not write anything to my logs file I edited the location of files but it still does not work I don't know where my errors are because it does not pop up
     my this is the contents of my app config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">

<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>

<configSections>
  <section name ="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>

<log4net>
  <root>
  <level value="ALL"></level>
  <appender-ref ref ="AdoNetAppender"></appender-ref>
  </root>
  <appender name="AdoNetAppender_Access" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <connectionString value="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Toshiii\Desktop\V#\Logs.accdb;User Id=;Password=;" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@thread" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="1024" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

and the contents of my system codes are

```
using log4net;
private void q_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        log.Info("Your data has been successfully saved");
    }
private void w_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 0;
        try
        {
            int y = 1 / x;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

what I want to see is that there are logs in my database, and I also did create a file that has the values from above so I'm wondering where are the problem in my codes

Comment: `<appender-ref ref ="AdoNetAppender">` should be `<appender-ref ref ="AdoNetAppender_Access">`

Comment: still does not work for me